# Ignore timeouts during jQuery.when

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have some jQuery ajax requests which I am running in parallel with a .when call. I want to ignore the ones that haven't returned after their timeout period.

Here is a simple form of it:

```
var ajax1 = $.ajax({url: url1,
    timeout: 1000,
    success: function() {
        console.log("1 done");
    }
});

var ajax2 = $.ajax({url: url2,
    timeout: 1000,
    success: function() {
        console.log("2 done");
    }
});

$.when(ajax1, ajax2).done(function() {
    console.log("all done");
});
```

In the above example, if url1 doesn't respond without 1 second, I still want to reach the "all done". I know how to trap the timeout error in each ajax call, but I don't know how to flag the error as ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just use [`.always()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) instead of `.done()` if you want all ways (success, error, timeout, etc...) that the ajax call is finished instead of just successful ways it finishes:

```
$.when(ajax1, ajax2).always(function() {
    console.log("all done");
});
```

The arguments passed to the `.always()` callback can be used to determine success or type of error from the ajax calls.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes I miss the obvious.